# loop over a list of json dictionary objects to return values

Tags: python, list, dictionary, iteration

This command in python returns the below image:

```
incidents = res[0].get("Contents", [{}])
return_results(incidents)
```

[image]

I want to iterate over the data objects and pull back values.

Such as:

```
for incident in incidents:
    lowestLevel = incident.get("Contents", {}).get("data")
    return_results(lowestLevel.get('id'))
```

I can't figure how to loop over the data to get the id for each "data set"

Anyone have any thoughts, let me know what I can expand on,

Thanks,

Boyd

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the data within incidents.

Comment: I don't know what that image is from.  If you print the JSON, it will be more clear.  You well need something like `for item in lowestlevel['root']['data']:`

Comment: Thanks @TimRoberts, tried your suggestion, but I got the following error:

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Yes, because you haven't shown us what the data actually are.  I don't know what that screen representation is trying to say.  You need to print the JSON, or pprint the Python representation of that.  Without that, we are ALL just guessing.

Comment: What schema is returned from `from pprint import PrettyPrinter; PrettyPrinter().pprint(res)` and  `from pprint import PrettyPrinter; PrettyPrinter().pprint(incidents)`?

Answer (score 0):

If `incidents = res[0].get("Contents", [{}])` and `for incident in incidents:` are both talking about the same `incidents` then it looks as though you are iterating over the dictionary (JSON) Objects in an array.

For your implementation would the following suffice?:

```
for incident in incidents:
    for lowestLevel in incident.values():
        for data in lowestLevel.get("data")
            return_results(data.get("id"))
```

Also here are suggested [looping techniques](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques) available in python's documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, though i'm getting the above with the suggested.

 AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'

Answer (score 0):

In the screenshot, the incidents have 2 values.
I do think the data you needed is inside the root.data.
you need something like for looping `for item in lowestlevel['root']['data']:`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, i tried what you suggested, but got the following error:

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Oh, so the return of `incidents = res[0].get("Contents", [{}])
return_results(incidents)` is a list.
figure what is indices is the root then your code will some like
`for item in lowestlevel[1]['data']:` if root indices is `1`

or better, share the structure of the dictionary